# Sharing canvas on Facebook or Twitter

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas, facebook-canvas

I am trying to share canvas element on Facebook or Twitter. I would like to share only this element as image from client side without using any URL but canvas.toDataUrl. Is it possible to create html link with canvas toDataUrl and post it using the way from the code? Or there is some other solution?

```js
document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    display: 'popup',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  }, function(response){});
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? there are many tutorials about canvas to images - that´s what you would need.

Comment: most tutorials for sharing images on Facebook require URL address and I would like to share it without using any URL and saving it on server. I saw great example at github.com/lukasz-madon/heroesgenerator but i wonder if it's possible to do it in some shorter way

Comment: You can't share image data. You need to upload it to a user as a photo. If you want to share you need to share a URL

Comment: it is possible without a specific url, but you really should try it on your own before going to stackoverflow. there are many tutorials about it, as i said. take a look at the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Creating

Comment: and this is a good start too: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL